# Is there a way to make a flexbox item resize based on another item?

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have an item, represented here by an empty div called `large-child`, which has a fixed height. This then controls the height of the grey `parent`. What I want to do is to allow the `child-flex` to fill the space vertically, so i set it to 100%. That doesn't seem to work though, and the only way to make the `child-flex` box fill the space so far is to make it bigger than the `large-child` one.

Is there a way to make this work?

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
  align-items: center;
  height: fit-content
}

.child-flex {
  display: flex;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: blue;
}

.large-child {
  background-color: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="large-child"></div>
  <div class="child-flex">
    <a>Item 1</a>
    <a>Item 2</a>
    <a>Item 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *What I want to do is to allow the `.child-flex` to fill the space vertically*

You need to apply:

```
align-items: stretch;
```

to `.parent`.

Then you can apply:

```
align-items: center;
```

to `.child-flex`.

---

**Working Example:**

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: start;
  align-items: stretch;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
}

.child-flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: blue;
}

.large-child {
  background-color: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="large-child"></div>
  <div class="child-flex">
    <a>Item 1</a>
    <a>Item 2</a>
    <a>Item 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `height: 100%` and set `align-self: normal`

This will basically "reset" the align property of the parent, and make the child behave as if that `align-items: center` wasn't set.

If you need the content of the `child-flex` be in the center vertically, then you can set the `align-items: center;`

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
  align-items: center;
  height: fit-content
}

.child-flex {
  display: flex;
  background-color: blue;
  align-self: normal;
  /* add this for centered content */
  /* align-items: center; */
}

.large-child {
  background-color: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="large-child"></div>
  <div class="child-flex">
    <a>Item 1</a>
    <a>Item 2</a>
    <a>Item 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be the minimalist change you can do is :

just replace `align-items: stretch;` in you class .parent, then remove
`height: 100%;` in child-flex

```css
.parent {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: gray;
  align-items: stretch;
  height: fit-content
}

.child-flex {
  display: flex;
  /* height: 100%; */
  background-color: blue;
}

.large-child {
  background-color: red;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="large-child"></div>
  <div class="child-flex">
    <a>Item 1</a>
    <a>Item 2</a>
    <a>Item 3</a>
  </div>
</div>
```